# Add KML as geometry column in fusion table?

Tags: python, kml, google-fusion-tables

I have a CSV file with:

- area ID
- area name
- URL of a KML file with the area boundaries: http://link.to/area_ID.kml

How can I load in the KML to a column in the CSV in order to upload it to Fusion Tables?

I'm working in Python. The KML is also available as JSON if that helps.

I know that I need to add it as a geometry column in the Fusion Table: I just literally don't understand how to get it into the CSV file so that I can then upload it to Fusion Tables.

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: I've tried to write the KML as a string to the column in the CSV (`<Polygon>....</Polygon>`), but Fusion Tables is refusing to import it, with a 502 error - perhaps because the file is now very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your CSV is valid (for example your kml values are properly quoted), it should load fine.  If you believe Refine is the issue, you can skip that and just upload your CSV directly via the fusion tables UI.

Comment: You were right that I was on the right track. The file was just too large for Fusion Tables to import, but I got it to upload eventually by reducing the complexity of the KML. Thanks for your help.